# Loading images from database to Jquery Vegas Slideshow

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-plugins

I´m using the plugin [Jquery Vegas Slideshow](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/) in a project and I'm trying to load images directly from my database into the slideshow script.

I have it running with the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.vegas('slideshow', {
        backgrounds:[
            { src:'images/slider/slider_01.jpg', fade:2500 },
            { src:'images/slider/slider_01.jpg', fade:2500 },
        ]
        })('overlay', {
        src:'images/slider/overlays/06.png'
    });
</script>
```

How can I populate the `background` parameter using Ajax?
I've read the documentation but there is no information about any server side language.

Answer (score 0):

By checking the source code of vegas plugin on github, there does not seem to be any method to update background images dynamically after plugin is initiated. But as there is one method called `destroy` I would suggest to try following code which destroys the background and overlay assigned and re-initialize the plugin with new set of images.

```
// Define backgrounds array
var bgimages = [
{ src:'1.jpg', fade:1000 }, 
{ src:'2.jpg', fade:1000 }, 
{ src:'3.jpg', fade:1000 },
{ src:'4.jpg', fade:1000 }];

//destroy vegas object background
$.vegas.desroy('background');

//destroy vegas overlay background
$.vegas.desroy('overlay');

// Pass shuffled array to Vegas
$.vegas('slideshow', {
delay:5000,
backgrounds: bgimages
}) ('overlay');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code :

```
$('body').vegas({
   overlay: true,
   transition: 'fade', 
   transitionDuration: 4000,
   delay: 10000,
   color: 'red',
   animation: 'random',
   animationDuration: 20000,
   slides: [
      { src: 'img/2.jpg'},
      { src: 'img/3.jpg' },
      { src: 'img/4.jpg' },
      { src: 'img/5.jpg' }
   ]
});
```